# Matlab: Extract values that I plot but which has not been stored

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a mathematical function *E* which I want to minimize. I get from solving this 16 possible solutions *x1, x2, ..., x16*, only two of which that actually minimize the function (located at a minimum). Using a `for` loop, I can then plug all of these 16 solutions into the original function, and select the solutions I need by applying some criteria via `if` statements (plotting *E* vs *E(x)* if *x* is real and positive, if first derivative of *E* is below a threshold, and if the second derivative of *E* is positive).

That way I only plot the solutions I'm interested in. However, I would now like to extract the relevant *x* that I plot. Here's a sample MATLAB code that plots the way I just described. I want to extract the thetas that I actually end up plotting. How to do that?

```
format long
theta_s = 0.77944100;
sigma = 0.50659500;
Delta = 0.52687700;

%% Defining the coefficients of the 4th degree polynomial
alpha = cos(2*theta_s);
beta = sin(2*theta_s);
gamma = 2*Delta^2/sigma^2;
a = -gamma^2 - beta^2*Delta^2 - alpha^2*Delta^2 + 2*alpha*Delta*gamma;
b = 2*alpha*gamma - 2*Delta*gamma - 2*alpha^2*Delta + 2*alpha*Delta^2 -...
    2*beta^2*Delta;
c = 2*gamma^2 - 2*alpha*Delta*gamma - 2*gamma - alpha^2 + 4*alpha*Delta +...
    beta^2*Delta^2 - beta^2 - Delta^2;
d = -2*alpha*gamma + 2*Delta*gamma + 2*alpha + 2*beta^2*Delta - 2*Delta;
e = beta^2 - gamma^2 + 2*gamma - 1;

%% Solve the polynomial numerically.
P = [a b c d e];
R = roots(P);

%% Solve r = cos(2x) for x: x = n*pi +- 1/2 * acos(r). Using n = 0 and 1.
theta   = [1/2.*acos(R) -1/2.*acos(R) pi+1/2.*acos(R) pi-1/2.*acos(R)];
figure;
hold on;
x = 0:1/1000:2*pi;
y_1 = sigma*cos(x - theta_s) + sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*x));
y_2 = sigma*cos(x - theta_s) - sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*x));
plot(x,y_1,'black');
plot(x,y_2,'black');
grid on;

%% Plot theta if real, if positive, if 1st derivative is ~zero, and if 2nd derivative is positive
for j=1:numel(theta);
    A = isreal(theta(j));
    x_j = theta(j);
    y_j = sigma*cos(x_j - theta_s) + sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*x_j));
    FirstDer = sigma* sin(theta(j) - theta_s) + Delta*sin(2*theta(j))/...
        sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)));
    SecDer = -sigma*cos(theta(j)-theta_s) - 2*Delta*cos(2*theta(j))/...
        (1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)))^(1/2) - Delta^2 * (sin(2*theta(j)))^2/...
        (1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)))^(3/2);
    if  A == 1 && x_j>=0 && FirstDer < 1E-7 && SecDer > 0
        plot(x_j,y_j,['o','blue'])
    end
end
```

Comment: `plot` [outputs a graphics object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-3). Store that to an array and then you can access the [coordinate data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_XData) later. Alternatively, just store the data in the same `if` statement as the plotting.

Answer (score 1):

After you finish all plotting, get the axes handle:

```
ax = gca;
```

then write:

```
X = get(ax.Children,{'XData'});
```

And `X` will be cell array of all the x-axis values from all lines in the graph. One cell for each line.

For the code above:

```
X = 
    [1.961054062875753]
    [4.514533853417446]
    [1x6284 double]
    [1x6284 double]
```

Answer (score 1):

(First, the code all worked. Thanks for the effort there.)

There are options here. A are couple below

**Record the values as you generate them**

Within the "success" `if` statement, simply record the values. See edits to your code below.

This would always be the preferred option for me, it just seems much more efficient.

```
xyResults = zeros(0,2);  %%% INITIALIZE HERE
for j=1:numel(theta);
    A = isreal(theta(j));
    x_j = theta(j);
    y_j = sigma*cos(x_j - theta_s) + sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*x_j));
    FirstDer = sigma* sin(theta(j) - theta_s) + Delta*sin(2*theta(j))/...
        sqrt(1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)));
    SecDer = -sigma*cos(theta(j)-theta_s) - 2*Delta*cos(2*theta(j))/...
        (1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)))^(1/2) - Delta^2 * (sin(2*theta(j)))^2/...
        (1 + Delta*cos(2*theta(j)))^(3/2);
    if  A == 1 && x_j>=0 && FirstDer < 1E-7 && SecDer > 0
        xyResults(end+1,:) = [x_j  y_j];  %%%% RECORD HERE
        plot(x_j,y_j,['o','blue'])
    end
end
```

**Get the result from the graphics objects**

You can get the data you want from the actual graphics objects. This would be the option if there was just no way to capture the data as it was generated.

```
%First find the objects witht the data you want
%     (Ideally you could record handles to the lines as you generated
%      them above. But then you could also simply record the answer, so
%      let's assume that direct record is not possible.)
%     (BTW, 'findobj' is an underused, powerful function.)
h = findobj(0,'Marker','o','Color','b','type','line')

%Then get the `xdata` filed from each
capturedXdata = get(h,'XData');
capturedXdata =
  2×1 cell array
    [1.96105406287575]
    [4.51453385341745]

%Then get the `ydata` filed from each
capturedYdata = get(h,'YData');
capturedYdata =
  2×1 cell array
    [1.96105406287575]
    [4.51453385341745]
```

Comment: Awesome, the first example is what I envisioned in my mind but was unable to do! Follow-up question, though: In the generated plot you'll see that one minimum is local and the other is global. If I just wanted the pair of x and y for the global minimum, could I use "min(y_j)" somehow to get only the relevant row of xyResults?